# OSX menu titles for Shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Japanese input method "Kotoeri" on High Sierra.
And I want to set some shortcut for "Edit Text Substitutions...".
Then I went to System Preferences...->Keyboard->Shortcuts, and press + button on the left bottom.
Unfortunately adapting ctrl+cmd+u for 'System Preferences...->Keyboard->Text->Edit Text Substitutions...' doesn't work.
After that, I tried again and again with these menu titles below. Neither of them doesn't work well.

- System Preferences...->Edit Text Substitutions...
- System Preferences...->Text->Edit Text Substitutions...
- System Preferences...->Keyboard->Edit Text Substitutions...
- System Preferences...->Keyboard->Text->Edit Text Substitutions...
- System Preferences...->Keyboard->Text
- System Preferences->Keyboard->Text
- System Preferences...->Keyboard

What is the correct menu command for "Edit Text Substitutions..."?
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: My first thought was "It's not 3 full-stops ... it's an ellipsis … " but my second thought was "Where are you seeing this menu item, 'Edit Text Substitutions'? I can't find it anywhere."

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. 
I will upload screenshot for the menu on OSX status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually test this as I don't get the same menu items in that menu, however, I'm tempted to say it's not working simply because you're not using an ellipsis … but 3 distinct period/full stop symbols ...

It ought to function if you add an App Shortcut to All Applications & set the menu item to
`Edit Text Substitutions…`
*[copy/paste this exactly if you can't easily find an ellipsis]*

[image]

Mac keyboard shortcuts don't need to be told which menu structure they're in, they 'simply work' if the item exists.

Comment: Thank you for your precise explanation.
Only one time ellipsis requirement & no need to tell the menu hyerarchy are both new to me.
To tell you the truth, in spite of your kind remarks still I couldn't have set the shortcut for this menu.
But I believe sometime, I will be able to do it.